# rfsrc() command in randomForestSRC package R not using multi core functionality

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore, random-forest

I am using R (for Windows 7, 32 -bit) for doing text classification using `randomForests`. Due to large dataset, I looked up the Internet for speeding up model-building and came across `randomForestSRC` package.

I have followed all the steps in the installation manual for the package, yet during execution of `rfsrc()` command, only one of the logical cores is used by R (same as `randomforest()`), the maximum cpu utilization being 25%.
I have used following command as per the manual.

```
options(mc.cores=detectcores()-1, rf.cores = detectcores()-1)
```

I am using Windows 7 Professional 32 bit Service Pack 1, on Intel i3 2120 CPU with 4 logical cores. Could anyone throw some light on what I could be missing? Any other efficient way to use `randomForest` with multicore utilization will also be helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `randomForestSRC` uses the `mclapply` function for parallel execution, but `mclapply` doesn't support parallel execution on Windows. `randomForestSRC` can also use OpenMP for multithreaded parallel execution, but that isn't built into the binary distribution from CRAN, so you have to build the package from source with OpenMP support enabled.

I think your two options are:

- Build `randomForestSRC` with OpenMP support on your Windows machine;
- Call a random forest function in parallel yourself.

Here's a simple parallel example using the `randomForest` package with `foreach` and `doParallel` that is derived from an example in the `foreach` vignette:

```
library(randomForest)
library(doParallel)
workers <- detectCores() 
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(workers)
registerDoParallel(cl)

x <- matrix(runif(500), 100)
y <- gl(2, 50)
ntree <- 1000

rf <- foreach(n=rep(ceiling(ntree/workers), workers),
              .combine=combine, .multicombine=TRUE,
              .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
  randomForest(x, y, ntree=n)
}
```

This example should work on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. See the [foreach vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf) for more information.

Comment: The first option suggested by you worked. I followed the instruction at following [link](http://www.ccs.miami.edu/~hishwaran/rfsrc.html) and it worked like a charm. My bad for missing it in the first place. Thanks a Lot Steve!

Comment: I tried RandomForestSRC with training for 7,500 records with around 20 attributes and it takes 17 minutes to create the model and 40 minutes to do the prediction for 2,500 records. It looks like it parallelizes the model creation part and so takes less time. However, it uses only one core for the prediction part.   Is there anything that can be done to parallelize / use all available cores the prediction part as well? The command used to predict is predoutcome = predict(model1, newdata = test)

Comment: @Bonson I couldn't find parallel support for the `predict` function in the randomForestSRC package. But I think you could split `test` into one chunk of rows per worker, call predict on each chunk in parallel, and then combine the results using `rbind` if the results are data frames, or 'c' if they are vectors.